# Is it possible to submit new GRE scores after having applied to an acadmic program?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, gre

I intend on taking the GRE but I haven't had the time to study much and so now I feel I am facing the option of either

- Taking the GRE anyway, most likely getting very unimpressive scores and applying to academic programs with these scores, or
- Cutting my losses and applying for programs the next time they announce applications (which, in some cases, is a year from now).

Is it possible to apply with my first scores as some sort of "provisional" score and inform them that I will be re-taking the rest soon? How much does a "bad first time, better second time" affect how admissions reviewers see applicants? In the case that extra background information would be helpful, I am a non-traditional student who already has a (short) record of research experience.

Comment: I am in a similar situation, though I decided to take it anyway. Now I am wondering if its even worth while studying for it more and send additional scores or just forget it until decisions are out and instead focus on my research position I currently hold...and if I don't get in anywhere I want instead just then only study for the GRE again...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly, the GRE scores are perhaps the most useless part of the application record. Good scores tell me that someone speaks English well, and is capable of basic mathematics. A bad score could just be a signpost of having a bad day, or perhaps some issues with English that don't necessarily translate into being a bad student or a bad researcher. (Just about the only thing GRE scores tend to correlate with in grad school is the performance in first-year classes!)

If you do have replacement scores, you can definitely send them to grad schools. They'll be considered, but they're not likely to sway a decision (unless the school has a minimum cutoff—which is possible for international students).

Comment: if its the most useless then why put us through the pain of doing it and distracting us from things that actually matter?

Comment: Because that's what's always been done. (Seriously. It's inertia more than anything else.)

Comment: is there a way to motivate universities to abandon such useless traditions? Or at least the first step to motivate to stop this?